# How to await a previously-started function in ES7?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-2016

I have two asynchronous methods that return values, one of which is needed immediately and the other might be in use, based on the first result. However, I don't want to wait for the first result to come in before kicking off the second method and create an execution sequence dependency.

Using ES7 syntax, I would assume that `await`-ing a `Promise` would be the same as `await`-ing a function that returns a `Promise`, but it doesn't work:

```
async function tester() {
    async function foo() { await setTimeout(() => {}, 2000)}
    async function bar() { await setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)}
    let rcFoo = foo();
    let rcBar = await bar();
    if (true) { // Some conditional based on rcBar
        await rcFoo;
        console.log(rcFoo); // It's a Promise object
    }
}
```

Two questions:

1. Am I even understanding the asynchronous nature of Javascript correctly? If the above code would have worked, would it have achieved my goal of running two asynchronous functions concurrently-ish, or is it just not possible to do it?
2. Is it possible to somehow `await` an object that is a `Promise` like I tried, or does it have to reference a function directly?

Thanks..

Comment: You should be able to `await` a `Promise` because `async` functions are just sugar around the creation of a `Promise`. You can't use `await` outside of an `async` function, though, so perhaps that is where your problem is.

Comment: This piece of code was already inside an `async` function.

Comment: That may be but your example doesn't show that, so I'm not to know :-)

Comment: The `await setTimeout` is going to wait for the `setTimeout` to be issued, which will happen instantaneously, not for the timeout to trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your code, `foo` will start right away, and then `bar` will start. Even if `foo` finished first, your code still awaits for the `bar` promise to finish before proceeding.
2. You can await everything as long as it's a promise, whether it's a variable or a returned value from a function call. As far as I know (I might be wrong), setTimeout doesn't return a promise, but it would be easy to convert it to one:

   ```
   async function foo() {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
   }
   async function bar() {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
   }
   ```

Comment: Correct, `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise but an opaque object that identifies the timeout. This object can be passed to `clearTimeout` to cancel the timeout prior to it's expiration.

Answer (score 0):

> I would assume that `await`-ing a Promise would be the same as `await`-ing a function that returns a Promise

The same as awaiting the result of a call to a function that returns a promise, yes (which is awaiting a promise).

> but it doesn't work:
>
> ```
> await rcFoo;
> console.log(rcFoo); // It's a Promise object
> ```

It does work, only `await`ing a variable doesn't change that variable. You can only `await` values, and the result of the promise will become the result value of the `await` expression:

```
let res = await promise;
console.log(res); // a value
console.log(promise) // a promise for the value
```

---

That said, `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise, so your code doesn't sleep three seconds. You will have to promisify it, like e.g. @PedroMSilva showed it.